# How to configure locale for all Fields and Inputs globally?

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

If I need to change the locale of a `DateField` or a `DateInput` I have to do it like that:

```
<DateField locales="el-GR"/>
```

and

```
<DateInput options={{locale: 'el'}}/>
```

Is it possible to configure all `DateField`/`DateInput` locales globally in a single place. I tried through 
 and it just translates labels and doesn't change how dates for example appear. Also I want how dates are shown to be independent of the translation language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A custom DateInput which would just reexport the default one with your own default props should the trick. Same for DateField